# C# add video file to stream

Tags: c#

I have a function that add an `Image` file to stream like this:

```
//sourceImage is a url for an image
public Stream AddImageToStream(string sourceImage)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(sourceImage);
            using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                using (var yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem))
                {
                    Image img = yourImage;
                    var ms = img.ToStream(ImageFormat.Png);
                    img.Dispose();
                    return ms;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I can't find `Video` class in C#.

How can implement this function for video files?

Comment: image and video are both byte arrays, and no difference for above code. if you do not have performance requirements.

Comment: Why do you create an `Image` object instead of directly return `mem`? Should be the same as `ms`.

Comment: @ZoolWay It's because I have been add some code to add watermark on image in old function and I deleted unrelated code and post my answer.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you already know how to turn the downloaded content into a `MemoryStream`:

```
public Stream DownloadToStream(string url)
{
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
        return ms;
    }
}
```

But this will need the video or whatever to fit into memory, there is no progress handling and nothing asynchronous. Also you should `Dispose()` the returned stream when you finished your operations with it.

There is **no** `Video` class in the basic .NET framework as videos are a complex topic. If you want to process it, you should look into some of the frameworks/libraries for that and definitely have to learn about asynchronous processing and streams.

*Update:* If you can use current versions of the framework you might be interested in using [HttpClient.GetStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=netframework-4.6.1). This will not consume all your memory. Still if you want to edit the video data you will require a  framework specialized on video editing.