# Is there any Audio Control for xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Is There Any AudioPlayer plugin for Xamarin forms (Like MediaManagerPlugin).

I want to play the song through link(http://----.mp3).Please Let Me Know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this one [Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer/)

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi theMouk  How to do this   player.Load(https://ia800605.us.archive.org/32/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3);

Comment: you can load it through a stream you have to see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798490/c-sharp-add-video-file-to-stream